# Virtual serial port in osx

Tags: macos, serial-port, virtual-serial-port

I am using snow leopard. I want to create a software serial port which will show up as a /dev/tty....

I want to use this virtual serial port to collect data from various program and IDE's such as arduino and processing.

Could anyone please advise me on how to do this. I have googled this question and i have looked at software like [netfwd](http://www.bsdua.org/netfwd.html) but they only provide serial port redirection.

I am new to osx and have not used linux before.

Comment: This question might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388889/mac-virtual-serial-port